# How to put database record count in GridPager in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid pager is showing the number of rows present. I want to show the number of actual records present in the grid from database? Actually the grid has only one extra row and that's being counted. I want to get actual database record count to show there.

Comment: jqGrid shows typically the "actual database record count" if your server code correctly fill the JSON response (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)). So to clear the problem you should append the text of your question with more *implementation details*: JavaScript code which you use, the JSON data returned from the server etc.

Comment: Actually the query returns actual number of rows in the data. but in the javascript, it changes it to other value by increasing it by 1.
I want the actual that was sent previously.

Comment: Actually I have added a row in the javascript. But while showing the number of rows, I want to show the actual data fetched or the actual number of rows that was sent previously. But I can't override the "records" as it's a read-only property. So, how to show it?